# graphic card crashes (black screen) after few minutes if i install a gpu driver

Tags: hardware-failure, amd-radeon, black-screen-of-death

I can't find a fix for this problem anywhere. I'll try to explain everything thoroughly

Three weeks ago I installed Warzone and tested different versions of AMD drivers. In the latest compatible version I tweaked the GPU clock setting (increased it a little bit) the screen went black for a few seconds then it came back and the clock setting was back to default.

The same day I played for hours without any problem. The next day one hour after turning it on, while on Chrome (watching YouTube) the screen went black again and I had to restart. After restarting, the screen went black after a few minutes. I ended up uninstalling the driver in safe mode. Afterwards, Windows 10 installed some updates. A week later Windows updated to 20H2.

In three weeks of having this problem only once the screen went black but after a few seconds it came back on and with this error : "display driver stopped responding and has recovered"

I haven't tried the `TdrDelay` fix (increasing `TdrDelay` value) - I am too scared to mess with these settings

**The Problem**:

- The screen goes black.
- The restart button works for only a few seconds after that I have to hold the shut down button to turn the computer off
- If any audio was playing at the time (game, YouTube or any other audio) gets looped and repeated (the last 0.5 of a second is repeated it goes gagagagag something like that)
- When i turn the computer back on  after a few minutes it happens again. Then I have to uninstall the GPU driver for it to stop.
- It doesn't have to be a clean uninstall (I don't have to restart
  after uninstalling the driver )
- Uninstalling the AMD software without restarting the PC works
- Uninstalling driver from device manager also works
- It only happens if GPU drivers are installed and the pc has ben restarted

  - no problems in safe mode
  - no problems without any GPU drivers installed
  - no problems if I uninstall GPU drivers
  - no problems in games
  - no problems if I uninstall GPU driver then install it again without restart

Right now I have to uninstall AMD driver every time I turn on the PC. Every time I want to play games I have to install the AMD driver without restarting.

I have tried these :

- latest driver.
- older driver.
- driver clean install.

I haven't tried these :

- reinstall Windows
- test a different GPU (can't)
- test the GPU with a different pc (can't)

**PC specs**:

- AMD R9 380 ASUS OC 4GB
- Radeon-Software Adrenalin 21.5.2
- Radeon Software Adrenalin 19.10.2
- intel  I5_6600
- 8GB RAM 2x
- B150 Pro ASUS
- Windows 10

Comment: You shouldn't change advanced settings unless you either know what you're doing, or are willing to re-install Windows if the computer becomes unusable. Most likely, the  "GPU clock setting" isn't correct and the setting remains on the computer even after you've uninstalled the driver. Change back any settings that you've changed. If you didn't document what settings you've changed and their previous values, you either have to continue testing different settings until you find ones that work, or re-install Windows.

Comment: thank you for the response . i only changed clock speed setting and it turned back to default . i didn't change anything else